# VirtualBox failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have not been able to get VirtualBox to start up successfully. 
I have made sure that hardware virtualization is enabled
but I keep getting this error:

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu.
>
> Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).
>
> Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
> Component: ConsoleWrap
> Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

Comment: What OS/VB version is the host running?

Comment: Wenfang Du: When you have had a suggested edit rejected, please do not submit the exact same suggested edit again.  Also, in general, please write better edit comments.